# Intellisense in Eclipse with NDK

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

What do I need to do (generally speaking) to get IntelliSense working in a Java Android project for my C++ NDK code (which is in the jni directory)?  I got the simple HelloJni project working, but w/o IntelliSense.

Comment: Maybe that blog post could help you: http://cdtdoug.blogspot.com/2009/09/using-cdt-for-android-native.html

Comment: That was very helpful, got me 90% there.